# Doubt in the definition of Centralizer

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Centralizer

**Given :** $G, H \le \text{Sym}(\Omega)$ and $G$ normalises $H$ means $\{g \in G \mid gH = Hg\}$

**Find :** $C_H(G) = \{g \in G \mid hg = gh, \forall h \in H \}$

I am not getting the difference $C_H(G)$ and normaliser of $H$, which is already given. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$gH=Hg$ only means that $gh=h'g$ for some $h,h'\in H$, not necessarily with $h=h'$. Take $G=S_3$ and a subgroup $H$ to see this in an explicit example.

Answer (score 2):

That' very simple: $G$ normalises $H$ if for all $g\in G$,and every $h\in H$, there is an $h'\in H$ such that
$$gh=h'g.$$
For the centraliser, $h'=h$ for any $h\in H$.

In other words, $G$ normalises $H$ if you have a homomorphism
\begin{align}
G&\longrightarrow \operatorname{Aut} H\\
g&\longmapsto(h\mapsto ghg^{-1})
\end{align}
and if $G$ centralises $H$, this homomorphism is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The centralizer tells you that 
$$
ghg^{-1}=h
$$
for any $h\in H$.

The normalizer is the set of elements $g$ s.t. for any $h_1\in H$ we have 
$$
gh_1g^{-1}=h_2\in H
$$
for some potentially different element $h_2\in H$.

You may check that the normalizer contains the centralizer, but the converse need not be true.